# RESTful route design

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I have a collection called `Entity` and each entity has a property called groups.

```
{
  _id: xxx,
  groups: [g1, g2, g3],
  others...
}
```

An entity have at most a few groups. The groups don't change a lot and I don't store it in separate collections. A group array object look like this:

```
g1 = {
  group_id: xxx,
  name: xxx
}
```

Also I have a `User` collection. Each user belongs to exactly 1 entity and 1 group. So basically we have a property called `user.entity` and `user.group` that references to exactly 1 entity document above.

When the user wants to get the entity information he can do `GET /entity/123`. That's easy. What about entity groups? The possible choices are

`GET /entity/123/group` or `GET /group`.

Method 1 is straight forward. You're already telling people you want to get groups in entity `123`. So you can setup middlewares to turn `123` into `req.entity` and return `entity.groups` directly. But for admins he might want to query all groups in all entities and this API seems not right?

Reason why method 2 is also ok is because after I get `req.user` I can check `req.user.entity`, query entity `123` and return the groups. But I feel like I have to do extra condition checks to get the groups. Also if an admin wants to query all groups we will just have to query with a different condition and the query conditions could be messy/

So what is the better design here? Is there one that's more RESTful than the other? (by the way 1 user will have exactly 1 group and 1 entity and `user.entity` will never change.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a similar project and my solution is a mixture of both of your possible choices :

```
GET /group?entity_id=123
```

With this, I can directly access groups via `entity_id` and can return all `groups` when `entity_id` is missing (ex. in case of admins).

This method depends whether your `groups` are nested inside `entities`, or they are independent (i.e can 2 different `entities` have 2 different `groups` with same id?).

If they are independent, you can also do something like :

```
GET /group/456
```

to access a group directly via it's id. However, this won't work if you've 2 groups with same ids. In that case, it's better to nest your url via `entity/:id/group`

Comment: ya the 2 use cases are like this. my thinking is one day when someone switches entity or each person belongs to 2 entities it would be difficult to simply GET /groups. dunno if I need to take into consideration of that.